# Quagga Javascript Barcode Scanner

Tags: quaggajs

Is there a way to scan Code 39 and UPC at the same time without changing the barcode type from the options? I tried adding both of them to active barcodes list. Still without changing the option to UPC or Code 39, it is not scanning

Comment: How are you trying it? There are two modes, static and live. Which one are you using? What are your options? Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 3):

I left you some questions with the details you should have given so people can help you more easily but I'll try to answer what I think that your question is. Not sure.

I think you ask why you need to set the reader engine before reading a barcode. I just read the [docs](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/) for a minute and it is answered there:

Inside the **decoder** section:

> "The most important property is readers which takes an array of types of barcodes which should be decoded during the session.
>
> (...)
>
> Why are not all types activated by default? Simply because one
>   should explicitly define the set of barcodes for their use-case. More
>   decoders means more possible clashes, or false-positives. One should
>   take care of the order the readers are given, since some might return
>   a value even though it is not the correct type (EAN-13 vs. UPC-A).
>
> The multiple property tells the decoder if it should continue decoding
>   after finding a valid barcode. If multiple is set to true, the results
>   will be returned as an array of result objects. Each object in the
>   array will have a box, and may have a codeResult depending on the
>   success of decoding the individual box."

You need to use a config like this one with several readers:

```
{
  readers: [
    'code_39_reader',
    'code_39_vin_reader',
    'upc_reader',
    'upc_e_reader'
  ]
  multiple: false
}
```

Comment: @eng I think that if you set "multiple: true" you will get an array with one result per reader so if would get a success at third position that success was with the third configured reader.

Comment: after I get the value from Dropdownlist , how can i put in the readers?     var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  x;

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. Please ask any unrelated question as another question. Try not to mix html problems with barcode library problems.